# Is there a utility to run FlowType js?

Tags: flowtype

Typescript has a ts-node to run *.ts files directly, is there a similar utility for FlowType *.js files? Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at Babel?

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing JavaScript that is valid to run in its environment (browser or Node?) except for Flow, then you can use [flow-remove-types](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-remove-types).

However, most code written with flow also uses other customizations that can't be directly run, like JSX syntax for React components, or `class` declarations. To compile all those to runnable JavaScript, you'll want to use a tool like Babel. There are instructions for [setting up flow with babel](https://flow.org/en/docs/install/) on the Flow site. Depending on what else is in your code, you may need to add other Babel plugins. Once you have Babel working as you want, you can use [`babel-node`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-node) to execute a file, and babel will first compile it down to executable JavaScript and then run it. (This is useful for development, but not recommended for production.)